# Wrist pain when cycling for over an hour

Tags: bicycling, wrist

I never had any injuries to my wrists in any sport, but I started to pick up cycling again (about 2 days a week) and when I go on for over an hour my wrists start hurting.

I used to do cycling when I was younger (competition, training about 6 days a week), I also used to do rides of over 4 hours, maxing out at about 6 hours I think. I never had this problem before, yet now I already start feeling it after an hour.

**Are there general tips to prevent this?**

Comment: You probably know to have your bike properly fitted, so I’m assuming that is not the issue. My wrists hurt after starting up and I found that shaking them out during the ride every 10-15 minutes helps.

Comment: I would migrate this to bicycles, but it would be closed as duplicate. See [these questions/answers](https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/search?q=wrist+pain). However, usually it is due to too long in one position or a bad setup. Poor gloves, bad handlebar tape, there are a lot of different reasons this could be happening.